# GraphQL: What I need to set up on my project?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I'm new on GraphQL and I'm trying to get how can set up GraphQL on my app (based on JAVA and rest). I've just read a lot of docs, but it's not clear what I need to set up easy this new layer.

1. Do I have to run a Apollo Server + Application Server?
2. Do I have to rewrite the existing SQL DB Schema in graphQL Schema?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to remember that GraphQL is [just a specification](https://spec.graphql.org/). There are many implementations of that specification, in most popular programming languages. You are not required to run any particular server or set up any particular data storage mechanism, so using something like Apollo Server is completely optional.
If you read the spec, which I highly recommend, you'll see that GraphQL has nothing to say about how you ultimately store data. It has nothing at all to do with your DB schema.
Read the spec and understand the fundamental principles. That will make it easier for you when you're trying to understand how to use a particular implementation of that spec (GraphQL-Java, for example).